# SCCM Server 2012 WMI Query For Missing Microsoft Patches On Specific Host

Tags: wmi, sccm, patch-management

What is the appropriate WMI query to ask a 2012 SCCM server for a list of missing Microsoft patches on a specific host that the SCCM server manages. For example, say I want to check which patches are missing on a Windows 8 client that is at IP 192.168.10.100. What WMI query could I use to ask the SCCM server which patches that host doesn't yet have installed?

Answer (score 1):

I'm unaware of a way to do that with WMI, but you can use the reporting functions of SCCM to get the same info.
Navigate to `\Monitoring\Overview\Reporting\Reports\Software Updates - A Compliance`
Launch the `Compliance 5 -Specific Computer` report. Fill out the fields. Sort on the `Installed` column.
Star(*) in the column means it has been installed, blankSpace in the column means its missing. For some reason they did not use True/False for column values.

[image: reports]
[image: c5sc]
[image: details]